# AntD unit testing table render

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, antd

How to unit test AntD Table render column?

Here's my code

```
const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Evaluation Form',
    dataIndex: 'projectName',
    key: 'projectName',
    render: (text, record) => `${!_.isNil(text) ? text : '---'} - ${record.employeeName}`,
  },
]

<Table
  columns={columns}
/>
```

Here's the result from the test
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The return value of render should be a React node or an object with a `children` prop which could be a string or React node. Change the render function to this:

```js
const columns = [
  {
    title: 'Evaluation Form',
    dataIndex: 'projectName',
    key: 'projectName',
    render: (text, record) => ({
       children: `${!_.isNil(text) ? text : '---'} - ${record.employeeName}`,
       ...
    })
  },
]
```